# curl error 77 when non-root user

Tags: linux, curl, trusted-root-certificates

On RHEL if I run curl as a regular user I get an error:

```
> curl -Sv https://example.com
* About to connect() to example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 93.184.216.34...
* Connected to example.com (93.184.216.34) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* Unable to initialize NSS database
* Initializing NSS with certpath: none
* Unable to initialize NSS
* Closing connection 0
curl: (77) Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
```

But if I run the same command as root, everything works fine:

```
> curl -Sv https://example.com
* About to connect() to example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 93.184.216.34...
* Connected to example.com (93.184.216.34) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=www.example.org,O=Internet Corporation for Assigned Names and Numbers,L=Los Angeles,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Mar 14 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*   expire date: Mar 14 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*   common name: www.example.org
*   issuer: CN=DigiCert TLS RSA SHA256 2020 CA1,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
> GET / HTTP/1.1
```

I figured it must be a permission problem, but the regular user does have read access to /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt and the files in /etc/pki/nssdb

Curl is using the same cert for both users:

```
> curl-config --ca
/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my LD_LIBRARY_PATH was causing curl to load some libraries that resulted in broken dependency.

After unsetting LD_LIBRARY_PATH it all works fine.